# Error: userdata validation failed: messages.0.name: Path `name` is required

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, cookies, jwt

---

Here are the details of my code. Thanks in advance.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////Client-side////////////////////////////////////////////

```
const submitContact = async(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const {name,email,message} = contact;
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/sent',{
    method:'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers:{
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "ContentType":"application/json"
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({name,email,message})
  })
//const data = await res.json();
  if(response.status===201){
    window.alert('sent!')
    console.log('Message not sent!!')
  }else{
    window.alert('Server errro..')
    //setContact({...contact,message:""})
  }
  console.log(contact);
}
```

////////////////////////////////////MongoDb////////////////////////////////////

```
const mongooseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  email:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  password:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  confirmpassword:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },

  messages:[
    {
      name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
      },
      email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
      },
      message:{
        type:String,
        required:true
      } 
    }
  ],
  tokens:[
    {
        token:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
    }
  ]
},{timestamps:true})
```

```
mongooseSchema.methods.addMessage = async function(name,email,message){
  try{
    this.messages= this.messages.concat({name,email,message})
    await this.save();
    return this.messages;
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}
const usermodel = new mongoose.model('userdata',mongooseSchema)
module.exports = usermodel;
```

///////////////////////////////////////Route////////////////////////////////////////////////////

````
app.post('/sent',auth,async(req,res)=>{
           try{
            const {name,email,message} = req.body;
            // if(!name || !email ||!message){
            //     console.log(`${req.body} is blank.`);
            //     return res.status(401).json({error:"error"})
            // }
            const userif = await usermodel.findOne({_id:req.userid});
            if(userif){
                const umessage = await userif.addMessage(name,email,message)
                await userif.save();
                console.log(userif);
                res.status(201).json({message:"added.."})
            }else{
                console.log("error")
            }
            }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
           }
        })
    
```//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
````

const express = require('express')
require('dotenv').config();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({path: './.env'})
const multer = require('multer');
const mongooseModel = require('./database')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bycrpt = require('bcryptjs')
const cors = require('cors')
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();
const auth = require('./middle/auth')
const usermodel = require('../server/database2');
const corsOptions = {
origin:true,
credentials:true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/pictures',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'pictures')));

```
I'm stuck in this error from past 24hrs.Please help!
```

Comment: 1. never use such formatting. 2. read exception message which directly says what is wrong

Comment: ie name is required but was missed